# Dragging some rows in the middle of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

So as i say , is possible copy each row and put it on the row below or as the same move field rows to the fields below? ( have and index auto increment of course ).The result should be the old row 40 content (fields) in the row 41 and so.

```
REPLACE table SET column1 = previuos(column1), column2= previous(column2), column3=(previous(column3)  where id > 20 and id < 300
```

They are not the last inserted, they are in the middle of the table and want to move it down , so that let me some empty rows ( with the index ) at the beginning of the selected ones

```
  INSERT INTO table (
  SELECT column1,column2,column3 
  FROM  table  WHERE id > 20 AND id < 200
  ) WHERE id = 30
```

selected row from 21 to 199 then inserted on 30 and ahead

thank you

Comment: What have you tried?  Can we see some sample data/schema and desired results?

Comment: Why do you want to replace what values are in those IDs.  The ID shouldn't matter, as it is just a reference point to the row.  If you are using the ID for something business specific, consider making another column, and you can then simply update the column for your business needs.

Comment: I a gree with the above comment. It seems like you should think of another way of doing what you want to do, to avoid messing with ids.

Comment: you got me on this , but since i try to do this few times , i am asking if there is a way , don´t really care about id , just grab bunch of rows and inserted few rows bellow (id maintain his order) i now even if i would rewrite in some rows

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of hard to understand, but if you want to duplicate the last inserted row, you could do something like that :

```
INSERT INTO your_table (
  SELECT NULL, column_1, column_2, column_etc 
  FROM your_table ORDER BY your_id DESC LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: what i want is moving bunch of row down (asc order) and made blank rows for new values.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a database table is not a spreadsheet.

However this will do what you seem to want:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET id = id + 9 
WHERE id BETWEEN 21 AND 199;
```

Comment: Thank's for try dude, but don't want to move anything on ID , but the rest of columns . Did you you now when drag a bunch of items on a list items down? that what i want to do , but without moving id , is and index,autoincrement btw